# Is this streaming from file or browser memory?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

In the following code it looks as though I can stream a local file without loading it all into memory at once because with larger files I get multiple chunks (see `console.log(chunk.length);` below)

```js
const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
const startButton = document.getElementById('start-button');

fileInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  console.log(fileInput.files);
});

startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (fileInput.files && fileInput.files.length) {
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0]);
    fetch(fileURL, {
      method: 'GET',
      cache: 'no-store'
    }).then(response => {
      response.body.pipeTo(
        new WritableStream({
          write: chunk => {
            console.log(chunk.length);
          },
          abort: error => {
            console.error(error);
          },
          close: () => {
            URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
          }
        })
      );
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file-input" />
<button  id="start-button">start</button>
```

But what I am wondering is, does `const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(fileInput.files[0]);` create a link to a local file that is then read via the ReadableStream from the fetch or does it load the entire file into the browsers memory and the chunks I am seeing are "artificial" or streaming from the browsers memory to Javascript Virtual Machine memory?

Comment: Browsers don't load entire File object into memory. And streams are the way to read data without moving it to memory entirely. So either way you are not loading entirely but in chunks.

Comment: cool, I was skeptical / was surprised that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`URL.createObjectURL( Blob )` only creates a symlink to the Blob's resource.

In case of a File on the user's disk, then it's only a symlink to that file on the disk, and if e.g you rename it or delete it on the disk, your blob-URI will point to nowhere.

Make the test yourself:

```js
let url;
inp.oninput = e => url = URL.createObjectURL( inp.files[0] );
btn.onclick = e => fetch( url )
  .then( console.log )
  .catch( console.error );
```

```html
<ol>
  <li> select a file <input type="file" id="inp"></li>
  <li> rename it on your disk or delete it</li>
  <li> <button id="btn">try to fetch it</button></li>
</ol>
```

Ps: in case of a Blob in memory, it's also just a symlink, but it will also mark this resource as active and thus will prevent the Garbage Collector to collect it, that is until you revoke this blob-URI.